# Match tag if a specific tag exists in the following siblings

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an xml where my tag `<T>` is only to be transformed, if there is at least one tag `<C>` following behind it as sibling.

```
<Doc>
    <T>T1</T>
    <A>A1</A>
    <T>T2</T>
    <C>C2</C>
    <T>T3</T>
    <X>X1</X>
</Doc>
```

should become: `T1A1T2C2X1`

I currently have:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Doc">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="A">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="C">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="X">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="T[following-sibling::* ??? exists C">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Not sure how to realize the `match="T[following-sibling::* ??? exists C"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="T[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::C]]"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
T1A1T2C2X1
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't give the correct results if the sample XML had a **C** element as the very first child element.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do it that all other tags are ignored, as I originally had it, with specific rules for A, C and X and ignoring the rest?

Comment: @stracktracer, Welcome. What do you mean? Could you provide some sample?

Comment: Kirill's answer works by excluding the special case (empty template) and by applying `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` to all other cases (`*`). This negative logic does not work in my case, I'd like a special match for the positive kinds of `T` tags separate to the other matching tags.

Comment: @stracktracer, So add templates to specific elements like in your sample in question. For example, for other `T`s: `<xsl:template match="T">logic here</xsl:template>`.

Comment: I don't really understand the answer, why preceding-sibling is used. Why not `<xsl:template match="T[following-sibling::C]"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>` and discard all other T's?

Comment: @stracktracer, What output should be for `<Doc>
    <T>T1</T>
    <A>A1</A>
    <T>T2</T>
    <C>C2</C>
    <T>T3</T>
    <X>X1</X>
    <T>T4</T>
</Doc>`?

Comment: Tag `<T>` is only to be transformed, if there is at least one tag `<C>` following as sibling, so `T1A1T2C2X1` (T3 and T4 have no C behind them).

Comment: @stracktracer, Maybe I misinterpreted terminology. So you can use `<xsl:template match="T[following-sibling::C]">`.